# Inverse match on header exchange in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq-exchange

When binding a queue to a headers exchange, I'd like to be able to match the headers that fail to meet the conditions specified in the arguments.

EG, whereas, some arguments to the binding : {customer: "foo"} will give me all payloads marked with this header {"customer" : "foo"}, I actually want to get the traffic that is any customer except "foo". I could declare every single customer, but it would be so much easier to have a "not" match facility.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an "Alternate Exchange" to capture non matching messages